# How do i submit form via ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i'm trying to submit forms without post back via ajax ..my code doesn't work

whats wrong in my script?

i'm new to ajax..help me with ajax scripts..

below is my code

note: i have two submit buttons with in single view. I want to make ajax call for both submit actions

my view

```
    @model AjaxEF.Models.Customer

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Main", FormMethod.Post,new { id="idForm"}))
{
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" />
    <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel" />
}
<script>
    $("#idForm").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
        var url = "~/Main/Result"; // the script where you handle the form input.

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $("#idForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data); // show response from the php script.
            }
        });


    });

</script>
```

my controller

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Customer obj, string save, string cancel)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(save))
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Customer saved successfully!";
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cancel))
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "The operation was cancelled!";
            }
            return View("Result", obj);
        }
        public ActionResult Result()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the other answer was deleted, but it was 100% correct. The URL you're hitting with your AJAX is your `Result` action, which does nothing but return a view. You need to post to your `Index` action, and since the form is already set to post there, the best way to get that URL for your AJAX is to select it from the form:

```
var url = $('#idForm").attr("action");
```